# A generalisation of the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, zeta-functions, birch-swinnerton-dyer

We know that the grand Riemann hypothesis is a generalisation of the Riemann hypothesis and Generalized Riemann hypothesis. My question is about the existence of a similar generalisation of the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivariant Tamagawa number conjecture generalizes the BSD conjecture. I am not sure if this is the most general conjecture available.

Comment: Reference can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_values_of_L-functions

Comment: and here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/96542/tamagawa-number-of-elliptic-curves-over-mathbbq

Comment: @ Marc Palm: Does there is a set of special L-functions where this conjecture apply just like the case of the Generalized Riemann hypothesis.


Comment: Yes this class of functions are called motivic L-functions. Following Scholl you can attach a motive to the new form so those L-functions are motivic. Examples include Artin L-function and Hasse-Weil L-functions.

Comment: @ Arijit: Thank you very much for clarification. 

Answer (score 4):

The Bloch-Kato and Beilinson's conjectures. Here is an extremely pleasant write up on that http://www.claymath.org/programs/summer_school/2009/BellaicheNotes.pdf
http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~nekovar/pu/mot.pdf
http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/u/peter.schneider/publ/pap/beilin.ps

Comment: I believe this is more special then the equivariant Tamagawa conjecture?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. The equivariant version is of course general than TMC.

Comment: More references http://math.caltech.edu/papers/baltimore-final.pdf

Answer (score 4):

A proof of ETNC => BSD can be found here: Guido Kings http://www.uni-regensburg.de/Fakultaeten/nat_Fak_I/preprints/Preprints2009/26-2009.pdf

For a generalisation of the BSD conjecture in *positive characteristic* to *higher dimensional bases* (over finite fields) see http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.5293 and http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.5294

Comment: @ Timo Keller: Received many thanks.